# Implement infinitely running broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want a `broadcast receiver` to be listening all the time, as long as the app is downloaded the `receiver` should always be listening, so how do I achieve this?

My current method is to use a `foreground service` to keep the `receiver` alive, but is this recommended?

In all the articles I've read no one mentioned `infinitely running service`, so should I avoid using a `service` in this case?

If not then how do I do it? I have some app which I'm pretty sure that they use `infinitely running broadcast receivers`.

Comment: Hosting your receiver in foreground service is the recommended way to ensure it's active. Only if broadcast you're listening for is explicit or in the exempt list you can declare it in manifest.

Comment: can you list some which you think have implemented indefinitely Broadcast receiver are just listener which listen to some system calls like Boot, network change when device is in foreground or background but not when killed.